# Krita3.0 - brush recognised on mouse but not on tablet

Tags: krita, hardware

So, I was using  Krita3.0 for animation, when I noticed that the brushes were perfectly recognized on using the mouse but the same brushes were just faintly recognized on my drawing tablet.

I use IntelHD2000 graphics card which supports Opengl3.1 and Direct3d10.1.
I have disabled the OpenGL display settings and followed all suggestions mentioned on krita's website but still, the problem persists.

Any suggestions would really help.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Perhaps it's a bug.  Krita 3.0 is old now.  Try updating to the latest version instead.  I use Krita 4, and there is no problem using it with my Wacom.

Comment: Hi,I did try Krita 4.1 (latest version )still the problems persists!Anything other than a hardware upgrade would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case above , Krita is able to detect mouse stroke but is not able to detect the pressure sensitivity(brush stroke almost invisible) of the drawing tablet ,making the tablet completely unusable.

It is evident from this that the machine's hardware is able to process the mouse stroke without pressure sensitivity but with pressure sensitivity , is not able to compute the brush stoke of the drawing tablet.

Inorder to make krita  recognise  atleast the tablet stroke (if not, pressure sensitivity),the pressure sensitivity has to be disabled for all input devices on this machine.**This can be done by setting the pressure sensitivity[Krita4.2-Settings-Configure Krita-Tablet Settings] for low pressure to "1" from it's default "0" value.**
(Note that this change is going to render the pressure sensitivity on the tablet unusable but the brush stoke will render on the canvas.) 
[image: Krita4.2 pressure settings]
[image: Stroke after changing pressure setting]

Answer (score 1):

I've eventually fixed my problem by switching to Firealpaca. It isn't exactly like Krita but works fine on my low spec PC.